# How to test that a set of distributions are located in a given order?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a set of population distributions; I obtained them empirically, computing histograms from very large populations (about 1 million per distribution). The population distributions might not have the same shape. The populations are all continuous or all discrete.

I want to test if the distributions are located according to a certain order.

More formally, let $D_i,\ldots,D_k$ be our populations, ordered according to a given criteria. We want to test if their distributions (probability density function) $f_i, \ldots, f_k$ are located according to the order.

I temporarily formulated the problem as testing that
 $f_i$ is shifted to the left of $f_j$, for each pair of populations $(D_i,D_j)$ with $i <j$,

So far, I performed a Wilcoxon rank-sum test for each pair of populations; using the version for large samples and the correction for ties, I performed the test on the population distributions. However, my distributions do not have the same shape.

I am wondering weather there is a better way to check the orders of distributions.

Comment: If the distributions might not have the same shape, I'm having trouble figuring out what "order" means. It made sense in the context of one being a "shift" of another but outside of that, I'm confused.

Comment: @Macro It could be that he means that the distributions are ordered according to means (or medians).  But this should be clarified.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, yes I was thinking that or perhaps the location of the tallest mode.

Comment: Indeed I didn't formally defined the concept. I'll try to describe it in an alternative way, but still not very formal: let $X_i$ be a random sample from population $D_i$; population $D_i$ precedes $D_j$ in the order if it is sufficiently likely that $X_i < X_j$.

Comment: Anyway, even the "same shape" case might be interesting.

Comment: Well, if they come from the same family of distributions (which is what I'm taking it to mean when you say "same shape"), then the values which parameterize the distribution can probably be used to characterize the $P(X_i < X_j)$. For example, in the case of the normal distribution testing a particular ordering of the means would be a way to do this.

Comment: @Macro, Igor's definition makes sense even when the distributions have different shapes.  His concern about using the Wilcoxon test is valid: although it tests exactly this kind of ordering, it assumes the distributions are merely location-shifted. What I wonder is whether there is any issue here at all: the question says that the $f_i$ are *population* distributions, not sample distributions, so it appears that no inference is necessary and all one has to do is compute the relevant probabilities.  Igor, is this the case, or do you actually have (large) *samples* of the populations?

Comment: @Macro If I knew their family, that would be a good idea. But in this case, the population distributions are obtained empirically and inferring the family doe not seem easy. Anyway, testing medians or means order might be an option. I am wondering if there is a way to do these tests in a nonparametric context.

Comment: Since you have samples from the distributions, you can empirically estimate $P(X_i < X_j)$ for each pair of distributions by re-sampling. Do you have a specific hypothesized ordering that you want to test or are you just trying to get the best possible estimate of the ordering?

Comment: @whuber In theory I have samples, in practice, given that they are too many, I stored the samples in histograms.

Comment: To all of you. I am sorry if I am imprecise, I'm a newbie...

Comment: @Macro I want to test an ordering

Comment: @whuber and Macro If I'm not mistaken, you are suggesting me to compute $P(X_i < X_j)$ from my population distributions. I guess that in this case $P(X_i < X_j) = 1 - \int_{I_i \cap I_j} \min(f_i, f_j)$, where $I_i = \{t \in \mathbb{R} \mid f_i(t) > 0 \}$

Comment: Yes, Igor, except (perhaps because I don't know what your $f_i$ mean) that integral formula does not look right to me.  A brute-force calculation to compare a dataset $(x_i)$ to another dataset $(y_j)$ would count all pairs $(i,j)$ where $x_i\lt y_j$, add half the count where $x_i=y_j$, and divide by the total number of pairs. An efficient way to do this comes down to manipulation of rank sums within the combined dataset: in effect, the Wilcoxon test statistic already tells you what you need to know.

Comment: Actually the Mann-Whitney form of the rank sum test expresses it in terms of how many Xi are < Yjs. But it is just a test comparing 2 dstributions.

Comment: @whuber $f_i$ is the probability density function of population $D_i$; I obtained $f_i$ empirically from the too large population sample of $D_i$.

Comment: @MichaelChernick indeed, it would nice not to use the pairwise approach, but I don't know how.

Comment: @IgorFobia I was not suggesting doing the pairwise approach in this case because (1) it involves several pairwise comparisons (creating a multiplicity issue) and (2) it doesn't necessarily give you an absolute order.  I was just commenting on whuber's remark.

Comment: Comparing/ranking variables using the stress-strength coefficient $P(X<Y)$ might not be a good choice. This has been discussed in terms of the [Pitman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._J._G._Pitman) closeness because this method leads to [paradoxes](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2290692) and [might not be transitive](http://xianblog.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/on-pitman-closeness/).

Comment: Do you want to test for stochastic ordering, specifically, first order stochastic ordering:  $X \leq_{st} Y$ if $P(x\geq u) \leq P(y\geq u) \forall u \in(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: I do not know the stochastic ordering, but it seems related to this problem. At a first glance, it looks to me that we might formulate the problem as measuring how much the stochastic ordering between $k$ variables is respected. But I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

The Kruskal-Wallis procedure is the multi-group equivalent of the Wilcoxon rank-sum test, which is akin to one-way ANOVA without the normality assumption.

A nonparametric *ordered alternative* equivalent of the Kruskal-Wallis test is the [Jonckheere-Terpstra test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonckheere%27s_trend_test).

That is, where the Kruskal-Wallis tests against a general alternative "at least one $\neq$", J-T tests against a specified order ($\theta_1 \leq \theta_2 \leq \ldots \leq \theta_k$), with "at least one $<$".

The test statistic basically consists of counting all the times the pairs of values (across groups) are in the anticipated order (the order specified in $H_1$), minus the times that pairs are "in the opposite order", though there are other, equivalent calculations (any calculation that yields a statistic with the same partial order will be equivalent).